# posting data to server with jquery and downloading response as file

Tags: php, jquery, http, post, download

I'm creating a file server, where users can optionally encrypt their files, and ideally enter a password in the browser to decrypt them on the fly and download them (in a chunked fashion of course, easier for PHP).  The decrypted data should never be saved to disk.

So right now the user enters the password, jQuery sends a post to the download page with the password and a variable "checking" set to true.  The download page then returns a json object with a true or false indicating if it could decrypt the file or not, this part works fine.

Depending on the response, it will either ask the user for another password if the response variable is false, or it will send out a new request with just the password and checking set to false, if the original response was true (correct password).

PHP then responds with the first chunk of the file to be downloaded.  Issue is, Firefox never brings up a download prompt.  Evidently you can't try to download files using jquery $.post()

So, I guess I need another way to do this client part.  Any help would be appreciated :)

Here's the applicable client-side code.

```
        Download: function(item) {

        if (item) { var file = Content.files[(item ? $(item).attr('id').split('_')[1] : Content.selected.files[0])]; }

        else { if (Content.selected.files.length != 1 || Content.selected.folders.length != 0) { return; } var item = Content['files'][Content.selected.files[0]]; }

        if (file['encrypted']) {

            $.prompt({

                input: {

                    html: "Please enter the password to download this encrypted file: <br /><br /><input type='password' name='password' style='width:400px;' />",
                    buttons: { "Submit" : true },
                    persistent: false,

                    submit: function(event, value, message, form) {

                        $.prompt.goToState('pause');

                        $.post("?p=download&id="+file['id'], {

                            password: form.password, checking: true

                        }, function (response) {

                            if (response.ok) {  

                                $.post("?p=download&id="+file['id'],{ password: form.password, checking: false }); $.prompt.close();

                            } else {

                                $.prompt.getStateContent('output').find('.jqimessage').html(response.result);

                                $.prompt.goToState('output');
                            }

                        },"JSON");  

                        return false;
                    }

                },

                pause: {

                    html: 'Please Wait... <img src="images/load_icon.gif" alt="" style="margin-bottom:-2px;margin-left:4px;height:12px;" />',
                    buttons: { },
                    persistent: true,

                },

                output: {

                    buttons: { Close: "Close" },
                    persistent: false
                }                   
            });

        } else {

            window.location.href = "?p=download&id="+file['id'];    
        }           
    },
```

Comment: ajax isn't meant for downloads...use `window.location` to redirect to download file, won't change page if server set to force download

Comment: Right, but it needs to be posting the password for the file, which is why I can't use window.location.href.  I suppose I could put the password in the URL but that seems like a terrible idea.

Comment: just use form for user to enter password, and post it without ajax to url that outputs the file

Comment: How would I do that in the context of the post above?  It needs to be done in javascript not in conventional html events.

Comment: instead of `prompt` use a form with same style

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using jQuery, so you could give a try to https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload and it works with POST too.

Answer (score 0):

I guess using a temporary conventional form is a good workaround.

```
    Download: function(item) {

        if (item) { var file = Content.files[(item ? $(item).attr('id').split('_')[1] : Content.selected.files[0])]; }

        else { if (Content.selected.files.length != 1 || Content.selected.folders.length != 0) { return; } var item = Content['files'][Content.selected.files[0]]; }

        if (file['encrypted']) {

            $.prompt({

                input: {

                    html: "Please enter the password to download this encrypted file: <br /><br /><input type='password' name='password' style='width:400px;' />",
                    buttons: { "Submit" : true },
                    persistent: false,

                    submit: function(event, value, message, form) {

                        $.prompt.goToState('pause');

                        $.post("?p=download&id="+file['id'], {

                            password: form.password, checking: true

                        }, function (response) {

                            if (response.ok) {  

                                $('body').append('<form id="encrypted_download" method="post" action="?p=download&id='+file['id']+'" style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="password" value="'+form.password+'" /><input type="hidden" name="checking" value="false" /></form>');

                                $('#encrypted_download').submit().remove(); $.prompt.close();

                            } else {

                                $.prompt.getStateContent('output').find('.jqimessage').html(response.result);

                                $.prompt.goToState('output');
                            }

                        },"JSON");  

                        return false;
                    }

                },

                pause: {

                    html: 'Please Wait... <img src="images/load_icon.gif" alt="" style="margin-bottom:-2px;margin-left:4px;height:12px;" />',
                    buttons: { },
                    persistent: true,

                },

                output: {

                    buttons: { Close: "Close" },
                    persistent: false
                }                   
            });

        } else {

            window.location.href = "?p=download&id="+file['id'];    
        }           
    },
```